# What is a CPX port or driver?

Tags: windows, printing, unix, driver, postscript

What is a CPX port?  More specifically what is CPX as relates to a Datacard embossing printer?

A buddy dropped off an ancient Datacard 150i embossing machine with me to see if I could get it working. It actually works perfectly but I can't for the damned of me figure out how to communicate with it.

On the MFG website they pretty much stopped supporting it after Windows 2000 and the documentation refers to setting up a CPX port which is a term I have never seen before and can not find any further information online after searching Google extensively.

To make matters more complicated I'm attempting to communicate with it on a Mac using the native OSX or I have VMware partitions setup with Windows 7 and Ubuntu.  But thus far I can't get anything to even see the device.

Answer (score 1):

> CPX ports are virtual ports that use your existing COM ports to communicate with your Datacard printer. No additional hardware is needed. Setting up an additional port in this way tells Windows to use a software component (called a Port Monitor) for printing to your Datacard printer.

From: http://www.datacard.com/downloads/ViewDownLoad.dyn?elementId=repositories/downloads/xml/150i_2XX_PrinterDriverInstructions_Win95-98.xml&repositoryName=downloads&index=0